# How can insert 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 with EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I want insert record on database by EF with Guid Id based on zero values (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000). On my *GetDefaultGuidUser()* method I can generate this value with default(Guid) but when I want insert on database I receive exception.

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'auth.Core.Users'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

```
var user = new UserRepository().GetDefaultGuidUser();
_context.Users.Add(user);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

However, I can update database with SQL script like this:

```
UPDATE core.users SET Id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What is the exception you get?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'auth.Core.Users'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

Comment: Are you sure the value is actually set in your model?

Comment: What GetDefaultGuidUser method returns? It seems like instance for user doesn't have value in Id property

Comment: The EF framework needs a value for NULL, so it picks this. There may be workarounds but more to the point: Why would you want this? It smells of a bad design.

Comment: I set default(Guid) on GetDefaultGuidUser() (I can see value). Id can't be null because is the table key.

Comment: @bommelding I need this zero value on database because our client wants this specific Id for "agent user"

Comment: Letting aside the question if this is wise or not, in general you can accomplish what you want by defining the attribute field in question optional ( .IsRequired(false) ) in the mapping. Since your error concerns the column 'Id', it's a required field and rightly so. If I were you I would not change this.